# Retrieve the user's facebook photos

Tags: facebook

Can I display somehow the user's photos in a 3rd party application? I found solution for use the profile image, but I want to use the photos. Do you know any solution?

Comment: did you read the documentation at all? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Oh. I found the Pictures only. It seems we can. Can you answer the question?

Comment: You have a fair amount of reputation on the site, I presume you can read documentation and follow example code?

Comment: Thanks Ed! It's a question to answer site, not a RTFM site. Maybe your answer will help on somebody later.